# HTTP client recommendations

Tags: erlang

I want some recommendations for a good HTTP client.  I have looked at hackney, is it a better HTTP client than the default Erlang HTTP client?  Thanks!

Comment: The answer depends on what you need from the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend [lhttpc](https://github.com/esl/lhttpc). It has a nice feature that connection may be reused after the request is done automatically.